# core.async go block fails to compile when protocol invocation form contains <! macro (multimethod '-item-to-ssa' can't dispatch on :protocol-invoke)

Tags: macros, clojure, compilation, core.async, multimethod

I was implementing a function involving a core.async `go` block, when I stumbled on a strange compilation error :

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No method in multimethod '-item-to-ssa' for dispatch value: :protocol-invoke, 
compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:2:3)
```

I experimented a little to try and strip down the problem, and found it was very generic. Say I have any protocol `MyProtocol` :

```
(defprotocol MyProtocol
  (do-something [this param] "some method"))
```

**The following code will not compile**, failing with the exception I showed you above :

```
(defn uncompilable! [me ch] 
  (go 
    (do-something me (<! ch)) ;; apparently, it hurts to use <! in a protocol method invocation 
    ))
```

However, the following 2 will compile without any problem :

```
(defn compilable! [me ch] 
  (let [call-it #(do-something me %)] ; wrapping the protocol call in a function
    (go 
     (call-it (<! ch))
     )))

(defn compilable-2! [me ch] 
  (go 
    (let [my-value (<! ch)] ; taking out the <! call
      (do-something me my-value))
    ))
```

Apparently, this has to do with the `-item-to-ssa` multimethod than can be found in the  [clojure.core.async.impl.ioc-macros](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/ioc_macros.clj#L489) namespace.

It seems to me the '`<!` inside protocol method invocation form' is a situation which the `go` macro fails to handle.

***Does someone have an explanation about this? Should I file a bug?***

---

This happened using `[org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]` and both `[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-alpha1"]` and `[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]`.

FYI, this happened when I was implementing a Ring-type middleware to marry http-kit async web server and core.async.

Comment: Would be great if you could file a bug report on the ASYNC Jira http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ASYNC

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it was a bug, not my misusing the library. I'll file the bug.

Comment: Filed the issue : http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ASYNC-99

Comment: I've ran into a similar problem when trying to use `go` in `nextTuple` method in a Apache Storm spout definition.

Comment: The linked issue was closed as "Not Reproducible" for a later version of core.async.  So it looks like the issue is now fixed, and this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nathan Davis commented, this is fixed as of core.async 0.2.374.